# Fitting a line of specific slope in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I need to fit a horizontal line into my matplotlib plot in python, couldn't find any simple method. so, was wondering if there is any simple way to fit a line of specific slope in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

horizontal line: `plt.axhline(.5)`
To fit a scatter plot, you can use `seaborn.regplot`

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made it clear, I'm not looking for plotting a horizontal line. I need to 'fit' it into an scatter plot.